# Is there an way to Inspect a broken link in an app?

Tags: ios

We have an iOS app that has a Watch Tutorial link to our website. We recently migrated our website and the page it points to is now showing a 404 error. We need to know what page the link points to so we can redirect it. Unfortunately in the app it just opens link to the page in the actual app and not in safari or any other browser so we can't see the website link.

**Is there a way to "inspect" the link *in our app* like you can in a browser to see where it is pointed to? Maybe some debugging software that can pull the app down and let me look at it?** Our app developers are unavailable right now and we want to get the app up and running correctly.

Comment: Look at the web server logs. The 404 requests will show the bad URL that wasn't found.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the Safari Web Inspector (Safari mac remotely debugging on an iPhone app/safari).

With this approach, you can inspect from you mac, any WebViews (or related) in actual apps.

Note : It won't work if you app make the request, but does not use web view to display the page.

See any tutorial on [how to enable safari web inspector](https://medium.com/@mattcroak718/debugging-your-iphone-mobile-web-app-using-safari-development-tools-71240657c487)

Comment: Another method : Configuring you iOS device to use a proxy like https://www.charlesproxy.com/ . So you will be able to inspect http requests.

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe some debugging software that can pull the app down and let me look at it?

You can use a web proxy such as [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com) to easily see all the traffic going to and from the app:

1. Install the proxy software on your computer.
2. Set the device to proxy through your computer.
3. If needed, install SSL certificates that will let the proxy see the contents of TLS connections.
4. Fire up the proxy, launch the app, and watch the traffic.